# Angularjs - More than 10 digit regex validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

How to accept more than 10 digit regex using ng-pattern in angularjs? Example from 1 to 12.

Answer (score 0):

`/^(1[0-2]|[1-9])$/`

You might not need the `^` and `$` in `ng-pattern`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
^\d{12,}$
```

May be it helpful.